How to get the final parameter passed to a ROS node when it's launched by *.launch.xml?
I have a project where the ROS node is launched by *.launch.xml files, in those files there are many other parameters.
I'd like to know the equivalent arg list passed to the .exe, like:
*_node.exe --arg1 --arg2 --arg3=somthing...

I guess this is the final command to launch an *.exe on any OS/platforms, but how can I get them or find a way to list them? Does ros2 launch provide the feature to print out the final parameter list?
If I can list them, I don't need to use ros2 launch anymore and just run the *.exe directly with all parameters.
